# AWS lambda on Cloud9 and codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cloud9, aws-codecommit

This is me looking for suggestions on how people use lambda on cloud9 and code commit.

Lets say I create a lambda function using the "create new lambda function" button on the "aws resources" tab. The function is created on the "/environment/myfunction" folder.

That's not ideal If the lambda is part of a code commit repository.

If I cut the "myfunction" folder and place it inside my code's folder (like "/environment/myrepofolder/myfunction"), it fails on deployment (yeah there are ways to fix it, but it requires manual intervention to update links, which tells me the cloud9 team was not intending that to be done)

Has anyone else come across this scenario?
Thanks